# Conditional type alias definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have a type like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    using foo = typename T::foo;
    using bar = typename T::bar;
    using baz = typename T::baz;
    // More of those...
};
```

I would like `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and equivalent type aliases to be defined if and only if the equivalent type exists in `T`. Solutions using `std::conditional` allow to replace it by something else when it doesn't exist, but I don't know how to make sure that it doesn't exist at all when the corresponding type doesn't exist in the template type. The code above causes an error when `wrapper<T>` is instantiated if `T` doesn't define one of the type aliases.

I can't make `wrapper` inherit from `T` because `wrapper` isn't supposed to do everything `T` can do. Also, using partial specialization would lead to some kind of exponential explosion and would quickly become unmaintainable. I could probably make `foo`, `bar`... template type aliases to inject an `std::enable_if` in a default template parameter but then users would have to write `wrapper<T>::foo<>`, `wrapper<T>::bar<>` instead of `wrapper<T>::foo`, `wrapper<T>::bar`, etc... and I don't want that.

Is there a simple yet maintainable way to define such a type alias only when the corresponding type alias exists in `T`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define `check_foo`, `check_bar` and `check_baz` traits which only have the type if it exists, then inherit from all of them in `wrapper`:

```
template <typename T, typename=void> 
struct check_foo{};

template <typename T> 
struct check_foo<T, void_t<typename T::foo>> { 
    using foo = typename T::foo; 
};

// ditto for bar, baz, etc.

template <typename T>
struct wrapper :
    check_foo<T>,
    check_bar<T>,
    check_baz<T>
{ };
```

It's one extra struct per type, but certainly preferable to the exponential version you mentioned. You could even make it a macro if you were suitably perverse:

```
#define DEFINE_CHECKER(NAME) \
    template <typename T, typename=void> struct check_##NAME{}; \
    template <typename T> struct check_##NAME<T,void_t<typename T::NAME>> \
    { using NAME = typename T::NAME; };

DEFINE_CHECKER(foo)
DEFINE_CHECKER(bar)
DEFINE_CHECKER(baz)
```

Horrible, I know, but I think you might need to pay that price if you really want `wrapper<T>::bar` rather than `wrapper<T>::bar<>`. If you use the macro version, adding a new type would mean just a new `DEFINE_CHECKER(newname)` and adding `check_newname<T>` to the wrapper inheritance list. Could be worse.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68afcaa8a885946)

Comment: That's the solution I had in mind and I was ready to try it. It's not really pretty, but still more maintainable than the other solutions without exposing useless things to users. Thanks :)

Comment: Dang. I was hoping that there'd be a nicer solution than this.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using inheritance?

Answer (score 5):

Note that the answer using `void_t` by @TartanLlama is fine as it is. However, in C++17 there most likely will be a couple of Standard Library helpers such as `is_detected_v` that will do the calls to `void_t` under the hood.

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

// helpers to reduce boilerplate
template<class Tag>
struct empty_base {};

template<template<class> class Holder, template<class> class Op, class Arg>
using inject_or_t = std::conditional_t
<
    std::experimental::is_detected_v<Op, Arg>,
    Holder<Arg>,
    empty_base<Op<Arg>>
>;

// add detector + holder for every conditional nested type

template<class T>
using foo_t = typename T::foo;

template<class T>
struct foo_holder { using foo = foo_t<T>; };

template<class T>
using bar_t = typename T::bar;

template<class T>
struct bar_holder { using bar = bar_t<T>; };

template<class T>
using baz_t = typename T::baz;

template<class T>
struct baz_holder { using baz = baz_t<T>; };

// wrapper is now simply:

template<class T>
struct wrapper
:   inject_or_t<foo_holder, foo_t, T>
,   inject_or_t<bar_holder, bar_t, T>
,   inject_or_t<baz_holder, baz_t, T>
{};

struct Test
{
    using foo = int;
    using bar = int;
    using baz = int;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected_v<foo_t, wrapper<int>>);
    static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected_v<bar_t, wrapper<int>>);
    static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected_v<baz_t, wrapper<int>>);

    static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<foo_t, wrapper<Test>>);
    static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<bar_t, wrapper<Test>>);
    static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<baz_t, wrapper<Test>>);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aBIQJsjAMHtpkeNB) Note that his is one of the very rare examples where libstdc++ 6.0 SVN trunk can (currently!) do something that libc++ 3.9 SVN trunk cannot.

This requires adding a detector alias and a holder struct for each to be injected type, and completely eliminates the need for a macro wrapper.

Comment: Really elegant solution! Of course one could do this in C++14 by implementing the appropriate helpers, or blatantly stealing them, like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cee230048c1a807c).

Comment: Oh, now that's an interesting solution :o

Comment: @TemplateRex Although this isn't what @Morwenn asked for, right? `wrapper<Test>` just tries to inherit from `int` three times rather than inheriting `foo`, `bar` and `baz` member aliases.

Comment: @TartanLlama thanks, I was too quick indeed, updated. Note that it now requires to add both a holder and a detector helper for each to be injected type, but the logic of conditionally injecting is now factored into a single `inject_or_t`

Comment: I'm a little confused how `empty_base` works. It seems to me as if, when `Op<Arg>` is invalid, meaning that `is_detected_v<Op, Arg>` is `false`, that we then use `empty_base<Op<Arg>>`. I can't see how that actually compiles.